# Not using Corda's FinalityFlow

Tags: corda

Let's consider a DvP transaction between NodeA (bond owner) and NodeB (cash owner), where

- NodeA sends bond to NodeB.
- NodeB sends cash to NodeA.

NodeA builds a tx which InputStates consists of: BondState (queried from its vault) + CashState (sent by NodeB to NodeA using SendStateAndRefFlow).

Let's assume that NodeA does not use Corda's FinalityFlow. NodeA sends the tx to notary. Assume that notary verifies it. Notary then sends back the tx to NodeA. Up until this point, both InputStates in the tx have been marked as consumed.

Now what happens if NodeA is fraudulant, and it does not forward this tx to NodeB? NodeB's cash has been marked as consumed, but it has not received the bond yet.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question.

I don't think we'd be necessarily dealing with a fraudulent node here, as Node B will have only sign the transaction having confirmed they are the new owner of the bond. In your scenario, the notary will have recorded the bond state with NodeA as the owner as spent and NodeA will be holding a bong that has NodeB as owner. As such, NodeA wouldn't be able to commit fraud, assuming only the current owner can sell on bond.

However, what we are dealing with is a malicious node, and we need to look at this from the perspective of what NodeA gains from this. Aside from creating a problem for NodeB, NodeA gains nothing. They can't go on to use the bond.

As such, you'd anticipate that NodeA opens themselves up to litigation without any gain.

Comment: Thanks Cais. From bond perspective, you're right that NodeA cannot use the bond anymore as the ownership has changed to NodeB. But from the cash perspective, NodeA is now the new owner of the cash, isn't it? So the way I see it, NodeA loses its bond, but gets cash from NodeB.

Comment: Yes, agreed. NodeA get's the cash, but gains nothing from preventing NodeB from getting the bond. They only open themselves up to litigation. All comes down to game theory :)

Comment: Yes, thx, I got it :) I'm wondering how to get NodeB alerted if it has been waiting for too long since the time it signed the tx until the time it suppose to receive the tx broadcast from NodeA to update its vault. Is there such mechanism in Corda? Or  can such issue only be settled off-ledger?